# mysql_num_rows error, but database is updated

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP problems regarding my PHP code

I create function that update database, for changing password. Here's my syntax

```
function changePassword($username, $password, $salt){   
$query = "UPDATE mt_user SET password = '". $password ."' , salt = '". $salt . "' WHERE username = '". $username ."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result == false){
        $num_rows = mysql_error();
    } else {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }
mysql_close();
return $num_rows;
}
```

I try this function by create some script:

```
    echo changePassword('user1','test','test_salt');
```

The database value **is updated** but, the function is showing some warnings

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in.....

What's wrong with the code? Because I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) is the wrong function here because what is does

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like **SELECT** or **SHOW** that return an actual result set.

To see how many rows were changed, use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows).

```
$num_rows = mysql_affected_rows();
```

---

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: hi, thanks for your information, yes i know i need to upgrade, but i still curious why this function is working but shows some warnings., now it's warning: Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @randytan don't pass any parameter to mysql_affected_rows…

Comment: i just change into mysql_affected_rows($result); the $num_rows is deleted, but still some warnings given

Comment: @randytan ___no___ parameters: `mysql_affected_rows();` (don't pass `$result`.)

Comment: i don't understand, please give some examples.

Comment: @randytan do ___not___ write `$num_rows = mysql_affected_rows($result);`. Write: `$num_rows = mysql_affected_rows();`!

Answer (score 1):

for update and insert queries you need to use `mysql_affected_rows`. mysql_num_rows only works for select statement.

Comment: i have try that but it getting me new warnings: Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: that means the query is failing.

Comment: the database is updated devzer, but the function shows some warnings.

Comment: change your query execution to `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

A little advice: replace mysql to mysqli. It's more secure. This example is with this one.

```
function changePassword($username, $password, $salt){   
$query = "UPDATE mt_user SET password = '". $password ."' , salt = '". $salt . "' WHERE username = '". $username ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if ($result){
    $num_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);        
    } else {
        $num_rows = mysqli_error($connection);
    }
mysql_close();
return $num_rows;
}
```